# substr using php

Tags: php, mysql

We want your help to write a function to add +1 to fetched results by MYQSL, we are currently getting max row (if there is else NULL) from mysql in format of 2011/345, so we want to post it back again after +1 to last part means 345+1 so final string should be 2011/346 to insert.
How can we write this function in php and should substr both 2011 and 345, Please help, thanks.

Comment: Who's we? Is this like the royal "we"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just shorter version of @ayk code

```
$rows = '2011/345';
if($rows){
    list($a,$b) = explode('/', $rows);
    echo $a.'/'.++$b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$rows = '2011/345';
if($rows){
    $parts = explode('/', $rows);
    (int)$parts[1] += 1;
    $return = implode('/', $parts);
    echo $return;
}
```

Should do it :)

Edit: Fixed some bugs :)

Edit2: Considered NULL result

Comment: why `echo` on array? you shoud use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` instead.

Comment: $return is no array after the use of implode but a perfect string.

Comment: its not working if we set $rows = NULL; we could get null output from mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data = "2011/345";
$lastNumber = end(explode("/",$data));
$len = strlen($lastNumber);
$lastNumber++;
$data = substr($data,0,0-$len).$lastNumber;
echo $data; // your new value
?>
```

Comment: not working, giving errors: `Notice: Undefined variable: lastNumber in /public_html/test.php on line 8`

`Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /public_html/test.php on line 9`

Comment: still there is an error: Strict Standards: `Only variables should be passed by reference in /public_html/test.php on line 8($lastNumber = end(explode("/",$data));)`

Comment: i didnt has that error in my machine, but you can replace line number 8 by: $params = explode("/",$data); $lastNumber = end($params); to pass it